# Convert Swift 2 code to Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, migration

How to convert the following code to `Swift 3`:

```
let size = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(view.frame.width - 26, 2000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin), context: nil).size
```

Comment: Thanks, return true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
let size = text.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 26, height: 2000), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin), context: nil).size
```

Comment: That worked super, thanks! Can you help me with a few others as well? Here they come:                                                                                       [return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 80)] to swift3.[layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 50)] to swift3. [return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, size.height + 16)] to swift3. Thank you very much in advance, tremendous help!

Comment: If you see in my answer how CGSize is done you could have copied the logic...`return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 80)
layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: size.height + 16)`